# Force an integer type in luajava

Tags: lua, luajava, luaj

Is there any way to force an integer type using LuaJava?  I am attempting, in LuaJ 3.0 beta 1 `(luaj-jse-3.0-beta1.jar)`, to create an instance of a `java.awt.Color`.  You wouldn't think this would be such an issue, given the Java API availability of constructors ([JavaAPI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html)).  The reason I am interested in forcing an integer into the constructor is that the `Color` constructors available take three and four arguments of either `int` or `float`.  Since Lua's number type is `double`, LuaJ (or LuaJava) calls the `float` versions of the constructors.

At first, I thought this wasn't going to be a problem, but after trying to use it, I noticed that I was receiving an errant `Color`.  The values were not being passed properly into the constructor, and `Color` object was essentially broken, with no discernible error (it didn't crash anything, it just didn't display).

Here's a quick example:

```
local j_color = luajava.newInstance( "java.awt.Color", r, g, b );
print( j_color );
```

If I pass `r = 1.0`, `g = 0.2`, `b = 0.2` to this constructor, and then print `j_color`, I will see

```
java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=1]
```

in the output.  In fact, I can use anything I want in `r` and `g` as long as `b = 0`, with no problem, but otherwise, it causes pain and suffering.

I am a little curious to know if anyone else has encountered this problem.  If it doesn't resolve, I will contact the PI on the LuaJ project about it, and report back.

As a side note: it would be a simple matter to construct a solution by which I use a custom-made Java function to be responsible for creating the `Color`.  I am more concerned that this problem exists, and whether there is some way to either specify which constructor you want to use, or to explicitly tell LuaJava to use integers, rather than doubles.

**Update**

I have also attempted to use the four-float constructor, and the same issue appears. If I pass in one of the following values: `alpha=0, 0.5, 1` the constructor functions properly. Anything else will yield the result above.

Comment: Err, you say you want an integer type, but by your example they are already converting to integers, and that's what you don't want.

Comment: It's not converting to integer before it's passed to the constructor. The output I print comes from the "toString()" method of Color, which prints an integer representation. I know the float-based constructor is being called because, if I attempt to pass integer values (range from 0 to 255), I will receive an InvalidArgumentException, stating that the values must be between 0 and 1.

Comment: Oh, so you want to call Color(int,int,int) instead of the default Color(float,float,float).

Comment: That's correct. As mentioned in the post, I wouldn't care to necessarily do this if the float constructor were working properly. But there is something amiss with its interpretation of the arguments. Perhaps I should try using the four-float constructor to see if it suffers from the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions [math.floor()](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-math.floor) and [math.ceil()](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-math.ceil) round down and up and always produce an integer.

For java.awt.Color, you may be better off using the single-integer constructor, since there is not a float equivalent.  That way the same constructor will be chosen every time.

Here's a working example:

```
-- return Java Color with r, g, b as floats in range [0,1]
function color(r, g, b) 
    local ir = math.floor(r * 255)
    local ig = math.floor(g * 255)
    local ib = math.floor(b * 255)
    local packed_rgb = ir*(256*256) + ig*256 + ib
    return luajava.newInstance("java.awt.Color", packed_rgb)
end
```

The failure case you provided will then have the expected result:

```
-- test the example
print( color(1, .2, .2) )

> java.awt.Color[r=255,g=51,b=51]
```

The issue is with runtime selection of overloaded functions based on numeric types.  For the java Color class, there are so many overloads that it triggers a bug in the selection logic within luaj for numbers whose float and double values differ slightly (i.e. .2).

Long-term it may be better if luaj exposes a mechanism to get at specific methods based on their full call signatures, but as of luaj-3.0-beta3, this looks to be the most reliable way to invoke the overload you want.

Comment: Thanks again, Jim, for your help. I keep stumbling across the bizarre problems, and you will be the one with the solutions. And thank you again for LuaJ. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can force luaj to use the 3 float constructor as follows:

```
function color(r,g,b)
    r = luajava.newInstance("java.lang.Float",r)
    g = luajava.newInstance("java.lang.Float",g)
    b = luajava.newInstance("java.lang.Float",b)
    return luajava.newInstance("java.awt.Color",r,g,b)
end
```

You can, of course, do something similar to force luaj to use one of the other overloaded constructor forms.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I technically wanted to call the three integer constructor, but your method is solid. I feel kind of silly to have not thought of this.